# Creating a class in JS OOP

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Can You help with this thing that I need to figure out. I started learning Js with OOP but I am kind of stuck with this, where am I making a mistake. This is the assignment I have to figure out

Create a class Car with a property that holds a number of doors and one method that prints the number of doors to the console.

```
class Car { 
    constructor(doors){
     this.doors=doors
     console.log(doors)
    }
}
```

Comment: figuring it out is much easier if you use a search engine and type `javascript class`, compare your syntax with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a method in the Car class to print the number of doors and then you need to instantiate the class with a given number of door & then call that method on it.

```js
class Car { 
    constructor(doors){
     this.doors = doors;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.doors);
    }
}

const bmw = new Car(4);
bmw.print()
```

Comment: so I always need some kind of a method in this case print method to display car

Comment: yes. this is exactly what you have asked for: `one method that prints the number of doors to the console`

Comment: @whatever well that was a requirement in your questions _and one method that prints the number of doors to the console._

Comment: the method name doesn't matter does it?

Comment: @whatever that's right. you can call it whatever you like.

Comment: ```const bmw = new Car(4);
bmw.print()``` is an instance is it

Comment: @AluanHaddad how this can be done without method? Can you comment that too?

Comment: @Hassaan I misread the requirements in the OP. A method _is_ necessary because one is requested. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @whatever bmw is the instance. you can create other instances as well and initiate them with arbitrary number of doors. for expample: `const Ferrari = new Car(2)`

Answer (score 3):

#### Hey

Yeah no problem :)

```
class Car {
    constructor(doors) {
        this.doors = doors;
    }

    printDoors() {
        console.log(this.doors);
    }
}
```

In JS OOP you have to define your member variables within the constructor by using the `this` keyword.
To access your variables somewhere else in the class you also have to use `this.

The `printDoor()` function has to be defined at its own to call it later on like this:

```
const numberDoors = 4;
const myCar = new Car(numberDoors);
myCar.printDoors();
// expected output: 4
```

Comment: Please fix your terminology. These are not global variables they are instance variables. They are anything but global. Otherwise your answer is solid

Comment: ```const numberDoors = 4;
const myCar = new Car(numberDoors);
myCar.printDoors();``` is an instance is it?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes you are technically right but I experienced that most people are confused when they don't know exactly what I'm talking about where (in my experience) everybody understood that global means "global" within the class. (Or instance of the class to be more precise)
So while helping others I often drop precision in favour to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: @whatever the 'myCar' is a instance of the 'Car' class while 'numberDoors' just represents a variable. You also could drop the 'numberDoors' and write it like this 'const myCar = new Car(4)' as we saw earlier :) 
The 'myCar.printDoors()' is used to call the 'printDoor' function of the 'myCar' instance we created in the line before that :)

Comment: I appreciate your intention but, by using "global" you are creating more confusion than you are alleviating. JavaScript programmers need to understand what global variables are. Just call them member variables or properties or whatever else isn't wrong and contradictory.

Comment: Agreed with @AluanHaddad